# How to find a differential for a function where $f : R^2\rightarrow R^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So let a function be defined as $f(x,y) = (xe^y+cosy,x^2,2x+e^y)$

How do I find $D(x_0,y_0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D(f)(x_0,y_0)$ is a matrix, whose $i$-th row is the gradient of $f_i$ if you allow me to name $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. Can you proceed now? Identiy your $f_i$ ad determine their gradients, evaluated at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: So is it a 3X3 matrix?

Comment: No. It is a 3x2 matrix. What is the gradient of each $f_i$? It is a 2-dimensional vector, viz. the vector of partial derivative of $f_i$ w.r.t $x$ and $y$.

Comment: so I found the 3X2 matrix. Do I need to also multiply this matrix by $(x_0.y_0)$?

Comment: You are evaluating the partial derivatives at some point $(x,y)$. Take $(x,y)$ to be $(x_0,y_0)$. You don't have to multiply anything; just evaluate your partial derivatives at $(x_0,y_0)$. That will be your desired Jacobian at $(x_0,y_0)$.